# Build a docker file/image for my new pallet

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust, docker

I am using substrate-node-template and recently I added a new pallet.
Now I need to build a docker file because I would like to send it for testing.

Any information?

Thank you.

Comment: Linux or macOS?

Comment: It is mac......

Answer (score 1):

As you probably saw; there is a [docker-compose](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/docker-compose.yml) file in the Repo which you can use in CI. It is not ideal since it re-builds every time.

Creating a docker image for the node can be done as shown [here](https://github.com/perun-network/perun-polkadot-node/blob/f0a29200bed5d2e4ec6fcb0ce8ae121f9124ff5a/node/Dockerfile):

```dockerfile
FROM paritytech/ci-linux:production as build

WORKDIR /code
COPY . .
RUN cargo build --release

FROM ubuntu:20.04
WORKDIR /node

# Copy the node binary.
COPY --from=build /code/target/release/node-template .

# Install root certs, see: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/9984
RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y ca-certificates && \
    update-ca-certificates && \
    apt remove ca-certificates -y && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

EXPOSE 9944
# Exposing unsafe RPC methods is needed for testing but should not be done in
# production.
CMD [ "./node-template", "--dev", "--ws-external", "--rpc-methods=Unsafe" ]
```

It is possible like [this](https://github.com/perun-network/perun-polkadot-node/blob/f0a29200bed5d2e4ec6fcb0ce8ae121f9124ff5a/docker-compose.yml) to combine it with the frontend template.
In any case; this should not be used in production since it exposes unsafe RPS methods which is good for testing.
A more professional Dockerfile can be found in the [Polkadot Repo](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/scripts/ci/dockerfiles/polkadot/polkadot_builder.Dockerfile).

Comment: What? You modified someone else's question and pasted your question in there instead? Besides this it is extremely self explanatory "failed to make network request".